# Trying to get div displayed according to id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display a div when I hover over an list item, and revert its display when mouse leaves. I have tried `hover()` but it doesn't work.

I have tried to add class `display` that is in css `display: block !imporant` and tried to add class only it doesn't even add to make it display

Can anyone check what is wrong with the code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".category").hover(function() {
    var cat = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(cat);
    $(".sub_cat_" + cat).addClass('display');
  });
});
```

```css
.display {
  display: block !important;
}

.no_display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories list-group">
  <a href="/product/Cameras">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="Cameras">
      <span class="category_icon"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-fw"></i></span>
      <span class="category_content">Camera</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></span>
      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_Cameras">asdasdasasdas</div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="/product/Clothes">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="Clothes">
      <span class="category_icon"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i></span>
      <span class="category_content">Clothes</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></span>
      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_Clothes">asdasdasasdas</div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="/product/Handhelds">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="Handhelds">
      <span class="category_icon">
      <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-fw"></i></span>
      <span class="category_content">
      Mobiles</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></span>
      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_Handhelds">asdasdasasdas</div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="/product/IT">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="IT">
      <span class="category_icon">
      <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i></span>
      <span class="category_content">
      Graphics Cards</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></span>
      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_IT">asdasdasasdas</div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="/product/TV">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="TV">
      <span class="category_icon">
      <i class="fa fa-television fa-fw"></i></span>
      <span class="category_content">Television</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></span>
      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_TV">asdasdasasdas</div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub category elements have an *id* `sub_cat_x`, not a class.

Therefore, you need to use `$("#sub_cat_" + cat)`, since `#` means an ID, `.` means a class.

Also, you can just use `.toggle()` to hide/show items.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".category").hover(function() {
        var cat = $(this).attr('id');

        $("#sub_cat_" + cat).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories list-group">
  <a href="/product/Cameras">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="Cameras">
      <span class="category_icon">
        <i class="fa fa-camera fa-fw"></i>
               </span>
      <span class="category_content">
        Camera
       </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i>
       </span>

      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_Cameras">
        asdasdasasdas
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="/product/Clothes">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="Clothes">
      <span class="category_icon">
         
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>        
               </span>
      <span class="category_content">
        Clothes
       </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i>
       </span>

      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_Clothes">
        asdasdasasdas
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="/product/Handhelds">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="Handhelds">
      <span class="category_icon">
        <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-fw"></i>
               </span>
      <span class="category_content">
        Mobiles
       </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i>
       </span>

      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_Handhelds">
        asdasdasasdas
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="/product/IT">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="IT">
      <span class="category_icon">
         
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>        
               </span>
      <span class="category_content">
        Graphics Cards
       </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i>
       </span>

      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_IT">
        asdasdasasdas
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="/product/TV">
    <li class="category list-group-item" id="TV">
      <span class="category_icon">
        <i class="fa fa-television fa-fw"></i>
               </span>
      <span class="category_content">
        Television
       </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i>
       </span>

      <div class="sub_categories light-border no_display" id="sub_cat_TV">
        asdasdasasdas
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay thank you for pointing it out. and let me bang my head on wall

Answer (score 1):

You're using a class selector `.` when you want an `id` selector:

```
$("#sub_cat_" + cat).addClass('display');
```